# Simple counting question- numbers in sequences.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm taking a counting/probability course.  Got this one question that I originally thought was simple, but my solution turned out to be wrong.

"How many $6$-digit sequences have a digit that appears at least $4$ times?

(For example, $383933$ and $020000$ are two such sequences. A sequence is allowed to begin with $0$.)"

Now, this is just simple PIE right?

We take the number of ones with 4, that's 6C4*10*10*10.
Then we subtract 5 number sequences. That's 6C5*10*10.
Finally, we add bak the ones with 6 number sequences.that's just 10.
S
My final answer was 15000-600+10, or 14410. But this wasn't right. Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The five-number sequences were counted five times each, so must be subtracted four times over.
The six-number sequences were counted 15 times each, then subtracted six times four times, so must be added back in ten times.

Comment: Thanks @Michael! I didn't realize I over counted by that much.

Answer (score 1):

Another method you could use is to divide this into cases:

1) There are 10 sequences with a digit repeated 6 times.

2) There are $\binom{6}{5}\cdot10\cdot9=540$ sequences with a digit repeated exactly 5 times.

3) There are $\binom{6}{4}\cdot10\cdot9\cdot9=12,150$ sequences with a digit repeated exactly 4 times.

This gives a total of $12,700$ such sequences.